# Holographic AdS/CFT intepretation of Cosmological Constant

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, cosmological-constant

I'm trying to understand how the value of AdS cosmological constant (or, equivalently, of AdS radius) affects the boundary CFT in AdS/CFT correspondence. I'd be glad of discovering something about the good 'ol N=4 SYM <---> AdS_5xS^5 correspondence, but the question has to be intended in a more general way. Precisely:

1. Can you provide me with a summary of all the occurrencies of AdS radius/CC in defining CFT quantities?
2. How is the CFT physics/matter content affected by the value of Ads radius/CC?